# Windows bat file is not working

Tags: java, windows

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\demo\java\jre

if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto jdkhome

:jdkhome
set JAVA_HOME=C:\exampl\java\jdk
echo heloo
```

In the above code heloo is printing always. I am getting java_home path dynamically during run time, in the
 bat file i am checking whether the path exists or not, if path does not exists then i am setting java_home path to C:\exampl\java\jre. But the code is not working may i know what is going wrong.

Comment: Please include your desired behavior and what is wrong in your question.

Comment: I am not able to edit it :(

Comment: In the above code heloo is printing always. I am getting java_home path dynamically during run time, in the
 bat file i am checking whether the path exists or not, if path does not exists then i am setting java_home path to C:\exampl\java\jre. But the code is not working may i know what is going wrong.

Comment: Is 'exampl' supposed to be missing an 'e'?

Comment: heloo is getting excecuted even if first path exists

Answer (score 0):

Your `goto` command virtually do nothing because it jump to just after the line with `goto`.

You have to avoid setting `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\exampl\java\jre` if the first path exists, so your code should be like this:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\demo\java\jre
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto jdkhome
set JAVA_HOME=C:\exampl\java\jre
:jdkhome
echo heloo
```

Comment: if path does not exists i want to do  set JAVA_HOME=C:\exampl\java\jre

Comment: @XYZ What does "path" mean in this claim?

Comment: jdk path i am saying